# Can we use passthrough authentication for Azure SQL DB from Azure Databricks like we do for ADLS?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

We understand that using pass through authentication at Databricks clusters allows us to access the ADLS from Databricks notebook.

Can we implement a similar thing for Azure SQL DB/ Azure Synapse databases from Databricks notebook without explicitly specifying AD username/password ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use service principle with Keyvault to implement Azure SQL DB from Databricks notebook without specifying AD username/password.

> **Prerequisite:**

- In azure active directory -> Go to app registration, register app
- Use key Vault to hold `service principle_id` ,`secrete` and `tenant_id` of app registration
- Provide enough permission to azure sql and create user.

Create an **Azure Key Vault** and **[Secret Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-ui)** -> **Create Scope** -> Enter the **DNS Name** (for Example, `https://databricks.vault.azure.net/`) and **Resource ID** -> Go to **Properties tab** of an Azure Key Vault in your Azure portal you get both DNS and Resource ID

**Code:**

```
import adal

resource_url = "https://database.windows.net/"

service_principal_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope", key = "ClientId")
service_principal_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope", key = "ClientSecret")
tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope", key = "Tenantid")
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id


jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://dem12gh.database.windows.net"
database_name = "sqldemo"
db_table = "dbo.Persons" 


encrypt = "true"
host_name_in_certificate = "*.database.windows.net"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)
access_token = token["accessToken"]

Df = spark.read \
             .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
             .option("url", jdbc_url) \
             .option("dbtable", db_table) \
             .option("databaseName", database_name) \
             .option("accessToken", access_token) \
             .option("encrypt", "true") \
             .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
             .load()
             
display(Df)
```

Please Refer this [Blog](https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal) by Daniel Moody